# Laravel - local.ERROR: #0 Database\Connection->runQueryCallback

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'm working with queues in Laravel, but from one moment to another the queues stopped working

basically, I get these errors in the log

```
[2021-01-27 04:42:41] local.ERROR: #0 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(638): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `gp...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(472): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('insert into `gp...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(424): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('insert into `gp...', Array)
#3 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert('insert into `gp...', Array)
#4 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2872): Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), 'insert into `gp...', Array, 'id')
#5 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(1508): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#6 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1051): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#7 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1016): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#8 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(857): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder))
#9 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\SavePlaceInsightHandler.php(126): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#10 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\SavePlaceInsightHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#11 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\PlaceScoreHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#12 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\PlaceScoreHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#13 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\PostHandler.php(51): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#14 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\PostHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#15 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\ReviewHandler.php(40): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#16 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\ReviewHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#17 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\PhotoHandler.php(38): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#18 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\PhotoHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#19 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\InformationHandler.php(32): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#20 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\InformationHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#21 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\OwnerRegistrationHandler.php(44): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#22 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Jobs\GprInsight.php(134): App\Services\Place\OwnerRegistrationHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#23 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Jobs\GprInsight.php(87): App\Jobs\GprInsight->createChainResponsability(Object(stdClass))
#24 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): App\Jobs\GprInsight->handle()
#25 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(40): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#26 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#27 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#28 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(610): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#29 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#30 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#31 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#32 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#33 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(118): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight), false)
#34 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\Queue\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#35 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#36 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(120): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#37 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(70): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#38 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(98): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#39 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(406): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#40 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(356): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#41 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(158): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#42 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(116): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'gmb', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#43 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(100): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'gmb')
#44 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#45 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(40): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#46 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#47 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#48 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(610): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#49 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(136): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#50 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#51 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#52 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(971): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#53 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(290): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#54 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(166): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#55 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(93): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#56 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#57 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#58 {main} [2021-01-27 04:45:07] local.ERROR: #0 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(638): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `gp...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(472): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('insert into `gp...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(424): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('insert into `gp...', Array)
#3 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert('insert into `gp...', Array)
#4 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php(2872): Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), 'insert into `gp...', Array, 'id')
#5 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php(1508): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#6 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1051): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#7 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1016): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#8 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(857): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder))
#9 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\SavePlaceInsightHandler.php(126): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#10 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\SavePlaceInsightHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#11 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\PlaceScoreHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#12 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\PlaceScoreHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#13 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\PostHandler.php(51): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#14 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\PostHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#15 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\ReviewHandler.php(40): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#16 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\ReviewHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#17 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\PhotoHandler.php(38): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#18 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\PhotoHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#19 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\InformationHandler.php(32): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#20 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler.php(37): App\Services\Place\InformationHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#21 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Services\Place\OwnerRegistrationHandler.php(44): App\Services\Place\AbstractPlaceHandler->next(Object(stdClass))
#22 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Jobs\GprInsight.php(134): App\Services\Place\OwnerRegistrationHandler->handle(Object(stdClass))
#23 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\app\Jobs\GprInsight.php(87): App\Jobs\GprInsight->createChainResponsability(Object(stdClass))
#24 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): App\Jobs\GprInsight->handle()
#25 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(40): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#26 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#27 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#28 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(610): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#29 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#30 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#31 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#32 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#33 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(118): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight), false)
#34 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\Queue\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#35 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#36 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(120): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#37 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(70): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(App\Jobs\GprInsight))
#38 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(98): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#39 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(406): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#40 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(356): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#41 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(158): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#42 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(116): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'gmb', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#43 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(100): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'gmb')
#44 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#45 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(40): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#46 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#47 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#48 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(610): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#49 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(136): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#50 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#51 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#52 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(971): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#53 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(290): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#54 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(166): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#55 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(93): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#56 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#57 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#58 {main}
```

All the rest of the functions work correctly, but when using the workers and the queues I have these errors in the log

this started to occur about 2 months after I stopped using these queue and worker functions

how can I solve it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because my data table did not have a primary key set. So, please check if your table has a primary key set.